# What font do you use for writing latex code?

Tags: fonts, editors, sourcecode

While mono-spaced fonts are generally accepted as the best option for [programming and coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689/recommended-fonts-for-programming), I feel they make it to hard to read longer texts and thus are not my preferred font for writing latex. What fonts are a good compromise between the advantages of mono-space (good readability of special symbols like $ ? / \ etc and brackets) versus being nice to the eye and making it a pleasure to read/write longer texts?

(I currently use Verdana, 11pt)

Comment: I think this might be off topic here.

Comment: what exactly is it that you don't like about Verdana? It is widely considered one of the most well-crafted screen fonts. For a good reason IMHO.

Comment: PS: my personal compromise is to simply not read my writings on screen (where I use Courier New, which I consider perfect in that context), but on paper, i.e. the medium in which a possible reader will read it as well.

Comment: I really like Adobe's [Source Code Pro](http://store1.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?event=displayFontPackage&code=1960). I use the semi-bold weight myself.

Comment: I use a `sans` font that has greek letters, superior and inferior figures and a reasonable amount of math symbols (Σ,Π,α,…) because my editor allows me to save them as TeX code and display them as symbols, so that I can concentrate more on the mathematical details and not TeXnical details. From this standpoint, the two best are DejaVu Sans and Microsoft's SegoeUI.

Comment: @egreg always uses comic sans

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it discusses qualities of fonts that are unrelated to TeX and friends as typesetting systems.